# redirecting old rewrite rule into a new one

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this rule on my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^business/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ./businesspage.php?name=$1&place=$2&id=$3
```

I want to make it shorter for SEO purposes, so there would be only two parameters, `$3` & `$1`.

However, I want the old URLs indexed on google to redirect to the new ones. How do I do it?

For example `/business/name/place/id` -> `/id/name`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this above your existing rule should work for the redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^business/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)$ /$2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then I assume you also want to modify your existing rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /businesspage.php?name=$2&id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks!

I had that idea in mind, just didn't know how to write it.